# how to set the dynamic table layout to full screen of the particular layout?

Tags: android, android-layout

I am trying to fetch the database using php,i fetched and shown in dynamic table layout,the rows where created according to the number of rows in the database,but the table layout is in center of the screen but i need it to be fit in whole screen of the mobile/tab.

i tried to change the height and width of the all layout used in the particular screen but nothing is changed can anyone help me to fix this.

this is my xml file.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".Colleagues_Schedule">


    <LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:weightSum="8">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical">
            <ScrollView
                android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="#3d455b"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" >

                <HorizontalScrollView
                    android:id="@+id/hscrll1"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                    <RelativeLayout
                        android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout1"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                        android:orientation="vertical" >

                        <TableLayout
                            android:id="@+id/table_main"
                            android:layout_margin="1dp"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" >
                        </TableLayout>
                    </RelativeLayout>
                </HorizontalScrollView>
            </ScrollView>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:orientation="horizontal">


                <Button
                    android:onClick="Back"
                    android:id="@+id/back"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="PREVIOUS" />

                <Button
                    android:onClick="Home"
                    android:id="@+id/home"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="HOME" />
                <Button android:onClick="Next"
                    android:id="@+id/next"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="NEXT" />
            </LinearLayout>


            </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>


</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

main activity

```
    package com.example.myapplication;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.GridLayout;
import android.widget.TableLayout;
import android.widget.TableRow;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.nex3z.notificationbadge.NotificationBadge;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;

import static java.util.Calendar.DATE;

public class Colleagues_Schedule extends AppCompatActivity {
    int i;
    String result;
    int size=20;
    Context context;
    int count = 0;
    NotificationBadge mBadge;
    Button buttonname, btnlogout, btntoday, btnyesterday, btntomorrow;
    JSONArray jsonArray_New = null;
    String[] ScheduleDates, StartTimes, Endtimes,Names;
    String Send_Yesterday, Send_Today, Send_Tomorrow;
    String ScheduleDate, StartTime, Endtime, Today, Yesterday, Tomarrow, Date,Name;
    java.util.Date date1, Todaydate, Yesterdaydate, Tomarrowdate,date2;
    TextView yes_date, yes_ST, yes_ET, tod_date, tod_ST, tod_ET, tom_date, tom_ST, tom_ET;
    private ArrayList<String> ScheduleDateArray = new ArrayList<>();
    private ArrayList<String> StartTimeArray = new ArrayList<>();
    private ArrayList<String> EndtimeArray = new ArrayList<>();
    private ArrayList<String> NameArray = new ArrayList<>();
    SharedPreferences mPrefs;

    GridLayout mainGrid2;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_colleagues__schedule);


        result = getIntent().getStringExtra("rootJson");

        init();

    }

    @SuppressLint("ResourceType")
    public void init() {
        TableLayout stk = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.table_main);
        TableRow tbrow0 = new TableRow(this);

        TextView tv0 = new TextView(this);
        tv0.setText(" Name ");//date
        tv0.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
        tbrow0.addView(tv0);
        TextView tv1 = new TextView(this);
        tv1.setText(" Date ");//name
        tv1.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
        tbrow0.addView(tv1);
        TextView tv2 = new TextView(this);
        tv2.setText(" Start Time ");//starttime
        tv2.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
        tbrow0.addView(tv2);
        TextView tv3 = new TextView(this);
        tv3.setText(" End Time ");//endtime
        tv3.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
        tbrow0.addView(tv3);
        stk.addView(tbrow0);



        try {
            JSONObject jsonObjects = new JSONObject(result);
            jsonArray_New = jsonObjects.getJSONArray("VIEW_SCHEDULE");
            //Fetching the data from the php file
            try {
                for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray_New.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray_New.getJSONObject(i);
                    Name = jsonObject.getString("Name");
                    NameArray.add(Name);
                    ScheduleDate = jsonObject.getString("ScheduleDate");
                    ScheduleDateArray.add(ScheduleDate);
                    StartTime = jsonObject.getString("StartTime");
                    StartTimeArray.add(StartTime);
                    Endtime = jsonObject.getString("Endtime");
                    EndtimeArray.add(Endtime);
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            //Initilize the arraylist to array
            Names = new String[NameArray.size()];
            ScheduleDates = new String[ScheduleDateArray.size()];
            StartTimes = new String[StartTimeArray.size()];
            Endtimes = new String[EndtimeArray.size()];

            for (int i = 0; i < ScheduleDateArray.size(); i++) {
                Names[i] = NameArray.get(i);
                ScheduleDates[i] = ScheduleDateArray.get(i);
                StartTimes[i] = StartTimeArray.get(i);
                Endtimes[i] = EndtimeArray.get(i);
            }

            //Search for Today schedule
            for(int i=0;i<jsonArray_New.length();i++)
            {
                TableRow tbrow = new TableRow(this);
                tbrow.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.row_border);
                TextView t1v = new TextView(this);
                TextView t2v = new TextView(this);
                TextView t3v = new TextView(this);
                TextView t4v = new TextView(this);

                tbrow.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.row_border);

                t1v.setText(Names[i]);
                t1v.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
                t1v.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
                tbrow.addView(t1v);


                t2v.setText(ScheduleDates[i] );
                t2v.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
                t2v.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
                tbrow.addView(t2v);

                t3v.setText( StartTimes[i]);
                t3v.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
                t3v.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
                tbrow.addView(t3v);

                t4v.setText(Endtimes[i]);
                t4v.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
                t4v.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
                tbrow.addView(t4v);
                stk.addView(tbrow);

                tbrow.setClickable(true);  //allows you to select a specific row

                tbrow.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        TableRow tablerow = (TableRow) view;
                        TextView sample = (TextView) tablerow.getChildAt(1);
                        String result=sample.getText().toString();

                        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(Colleagues_Schedule.this, result, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                        toast.show();
                    }
                });

            }

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
}

}
```

and this is my output scrren.

[output screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QdAtJ.png)

Comment: Can you post how you are adding dynamic rows?

Comment: At least, you are not setting any constraints while using `ConstraintLayout`. And there is no need in multiple nested `LinearLayouts`. I suggest you to read more about layouts in general to have a better understanding what each view does.

Comment: have you try ScrollView with android:fillViewport="true" ?

Comment: i have posted the main activity can you check it @ ayush-khare

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try giving layout params to every row you add dynamically and update your `init()` function like below:

```
@SuppressLint("ResourceType")
public void init() {
    TableLayout stk = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.table_main);
    TableRow tbrow0 = new TableRow(this);
    //added layout params and weight
    tbrow0.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1.0f));

    TextView tv0 = new TextView(this);
    tv0.setText(" Name ");//date
    tv0.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
    //added layout params and weight
    tv0.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1.0f));
    tbrow0.addView(tv0);

    TextView tv1 = new TextView(this);
    tv1.setText(" Date ");//name
    tv1.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
    //added layout params and weight
    tv1.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1.0f));
    tbrow0.addView(tv1);

    TextView tv2 = new TextView(this);
    tv2.setText(" Start Time ");//starttime
    tv2.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
    //added layout params and weight
    tv2.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1.0f));
    tbrow0.addView(tv2);

    TextView tv3 = new TextView(this);
    tv3.setText(" End Time ");//endtime
    tv3.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
    //added layout params and weight
    tv3.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1.0f));
    tbrow0.addView(tv3);

    //added layout params and weight
    stk.addView(tbrow0, new TableLayout.LayoutParams(TableLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, TableLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

    try {
        JSONObject jsonObjects = new JSONObject(result);
        jsonArray_New = jsonObjects.getJSONArray("VIEW_SCHEDULE");
        //Fetching the data from the php file
        try {
            for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray_New.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray_New.getJSONObject(i);
                Name = jsonObject.getString("Name");
                NameArray.add(Name);
                ScheduleDate = jsonObject.getString("ScheduleDate");
                ScheduleDateArray.add(ScheduleDate);
                StartTime = jsonObject.getString("StartTime");
                StartTimeArray.add(StartTime);
                Endtime = jsonObject.getString("Endtime");
                EndtimeArray.add(Endtime);
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        //Initilize the arraylist to array
        Names = new String[NameArray.size()];
        ScheduleDates = new String[ScheduleDateArray.size()];
        StartTimes = new String[StartTimeArray.size()];
        Endtimes = new String[EndtimeArray.size()];

        for (int i = 0; i < ScheduleDateArray.size(); i++) {
            Names[i] = NameArray.get(i);
            ScheduleDates[i] = ScheduleDateArray.get(i);
            StartTimes[i] = StartTimeArray.get(i);
            Endtimes[i] = EndtimeArray.get(i);
        }

        //Search for Today schedule
        for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray_New.length(); i++) {
            TableRow tbrow = new TableRow(this);
            tbrow.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.row_border);
    //added layout params and weight
            tbrow.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                    TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1.0f));
            TextView t1v = new TextView(this);
            TextView t2v = new TextView(this);
            TextView t3v = new TextView(this);
            TextView t4v = new TextView(this);

            tbrow.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.row_border);

            t1v.setText(Names[i]);
            t1v.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
            t1v.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
    //added layout params and weight
            t1v.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                    TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1.0f));
            tbrow.addView(t1v);

            t2v.setText(ScheduleDates[i]);
            t2v.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
            t2v.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
    //added layout params and weight
            t2v.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                    TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1.0f));
            tbrow.addView(t2v);

            t3v.setText(StartTimes[i]);
            t3v.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
            t3v.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
    //added layout params and weight
            t3v.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                    TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1.0f));
            tbrow.addView(t3v);

            t4v.setText(Endtimes[i]);
            t4v.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
            t4v.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
    //added layout params and weight
            t4v.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                    TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1.0f));
            tbrow.addView(t4v);

    //added layout params and weight
            stk.addView(tbrow, new TableLayout.LayoutParams(TableLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, TableLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

            tbrow.setClickable(true);  //allows you to select a specific row

            tbrow.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    TableRow tablerow = (TableRow) view;
                    TextView sample = (TextView) tablerow.getChildAt(1);
                    String result = sample.getText().toString();

                    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, result, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                    toast.show();
                }
            });

        }

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

And provide `android:fillViewport="true"` to your `ScrollView` with **id=scrollView1** and `HorizontalScrollView` with **id=hscrll1**

Comment: Please check my updated answer, I have written comments with the updated changes I have made